# Sorting date in %W %M %d %Y format in mySql

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

I want to sort date in msSQL database, which is stored like: Wednesday, February 13, 2016

For example, I have:

-Thursday, January 7, 2016

-Wednesday, February 10, 2016

- Wednesday, December 30, 2015
- Wednesday, December 9, 2015

and this should be sorted like:

- Wednesday, December 9, 2015
- Wednesday, December 30, 2015
- Thursday, January 7, 2016
- Wednesday, February 10, 2016

I have tried following query:
select * from appointment order by date asc;

But it sorts alphabetically, by just seeing first letter of week.
How should I sort it by actual timing.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    SELECT
            * 
    FROM
            appointment 
    ORDER BY  
            STR_TO_DATE(date, '%W, %M %e, %Y');
```

Comment: Thanx for ur response @Hytool but for running this query what should be the datatype of date column?

Comment: well, I considered it as VARCHAR ! what is it, at your side ?

Comment: "Additional information: 'STR_TO_DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name." I get this error

Comment: are you using MySQL or SQL Server ????? you tagged your question with < mysql > ? if you have SQL server, try the same query with CONVERT() function in-place of  STR_TO_DATE !

Comment: Yeah, I am using SQL server with C# in VS 2015. and I am trying to pick date from datetimepicker than storing it in database. This all is done successfully but sorting is the issue. While using 'convert', I get this issue:'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'.

Comment: let me tell you one thing, If I was in this situation, I would not save/insert this date format in my database, the format has to be in proper datatype, However if you still want to do it,  Let me give you a hint if it could be helpful, truncate the DAY name from the field, convert Month name into Month number, and then use CONVERT function to convert it into datetime ! you may to use SUBSTRING, CHARINDEX, DATEPART or CONVERT functions. you would surely be facing performance issues if you would do so !